# what is the use of count-- in the program

Tags: java, loops

I'm a beginner in Java, and I was looking for a program to make a star diamond.
Here is what I found on the net:

```
public class JavaStarPattern {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number = 5;
    int count = number - 1;
    for (int k = 1; k <= number; k++) {
      for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        System.out.print(" ");
      count--;
      for (int i = 1; i <= 2 * k - 1; i++)
        System.out.print("*");
      System.out.println();
    }
    count = 1;
    for (int k = 1; k <= number - 1; k++) {
      for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        System.out.print(" ");
      count++;
      for (int i = 1; i <= 2 * (number - k) - 1; i++)
        System.out.print("*");
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

What is the use of `count--`, and `count++`?
Why we need `count--`, in the second `for` loop statement, when we are using `i++` in the same statement?

Comment: You might want to read the [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) on operators.

Comment: [Nuts and Bolts: The Unary Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)

Comment: You might also want to just debug the code and step through it to see what it does, step by step.

Comment: `count` = amount of spaces; `number` = amount of rows; `i`= used for rows. So if you know this it´s easy to understand what it´s doing and the logic.

Comment: There is no need to say that you found the code on the net, that is why you have got many down votes.

Answer (score 1):

**count** (count++/count--) is used to keep the track of number of spaces to be added in each line, so

- in 1st for loop, it is initialized as n-1 and then reduced to 0
- and in 2nd for loop it is initialized to 1 and then increased to n-1

whereas **i++** is used to print spaces and *(asterisk) on each line.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see the full programm with better naming and a few lines of doc if you dont understand your code - doc it the right way....

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int rows = 5;
    int spaces = rows - 1;
    int stars = 1;

    // Print rows forwards
    for (int k = 0; k < rows; k++) {
        // print spaces at linebeginning
        for (int i = 0; i < spaces; i++)
            System.out.print(" ");

        // print stars for this line
        for (int i = 0; i < stars; i++)
            System.out.print("*");

        // setting for next line
        spaces--; // spaces -= 1
        stars += 2; // add 2 more stars for each row
        System.out.println();
    }

    // turn around diamond
    spaces = 1; // because longest line was printed before.
    rows--; // need 1 row less
    stars = ((rows - 1) * 2) - 1; // calculate stars MAX backwards

    // print fows backwards
    for (int k = 0; k < rows; k++) {

        for (int i = 0; i < spaces; i++)
            System.out.print(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < stars; i++)
            System.out.print("*");

        // Settings
        spaces++;
        stars--;
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```